# Making a Button restart the activity

Tags: java, android, xml

Ok so I know this may seem simple, I mean I thought it was. But essentially I want the restartActivity method to restart the activity.

First thing I did was create the button and had the line of code in the xml as such.
`android:onClick="restartActivity"`

then my class contains the restartActivity Method as such

```
public void restartActivity()
{
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I try this what ends up happening is the stopped working dialog box. So my question is simply why is this not working. I made sure I made the restart button in the right layout, I checked to make sure all needed references were made. And the android manifest is all correct. It wasn't until I added those two lines it started crashing. I should also mention my target api is 8 and one of the answers suggested was an api 11 or higher. As eclipse "kindly" let me knew.

Comment: Please add the error you get.
Do you close the activity before starting it up again?

Comment: Did you try using recreate method?

Comment: The answers below will help with your problem but I think you should make sure this is what you want to do. If you need to refresh a `View` or update data then there are better ways. There aren't a lot of reasons to completely restart an `Activity` from within itself

Comment: Well it's not an error per se. It's just the annoying dialog popup box that says "Unfortunately <insert appname here> has stopped working"

Comment: And codeMagic, the only reason I want to restart is because in this case I want to be back at the first page of the main activity from the first page with all values erased and set back to blank.

Answer (score 5):

Activity class already provides this method:

```
 public void recreate ()
```

Since: API Level 11
Cause the Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

So you can do something like this,

```
public void Restart()
{
   this.recreate();
}
```

If you are outside of the activity, then simply:

```
public void Restart(Context ctx)
    {
       //geting activty from context
       Activity a = (Activity)ctx;
       //forcing activity to recrete
       a.recreate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Activity context . You are referring to this in on button click. This refers to current context which is button in your case.

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(ActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
```

This will create a new instance of the same activity.

Say you have MainActivity. This is on the back

On button click start the same activity and call finish()

```
Intent t= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(t);
finish();
```

Edit:

In your first activity say on button click

```
Intent t= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(t);
finish();
```

In your second Activity  on button click

```
Intent t= new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
startActivity(t);
finish();
```

Comment: So wait does that all go in the onClick method in my second activity? I guess what is code I could launch from my second activity to relaunch the first activity? I guess that would be a better way to do this.

Comment: You could do the same in the second activity. But a new instance of the activity will be created. You need to clear the back stack if in that case.

Answer (score 0):

your click may Like

```
 public void restartActivity(View view)
     {
         // do your work Here
         Intent intent= new Intent(currentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
```